# Flutter only build one apk variant

Tags: android, flutter, dart

Usually when i run `flutter build apk --split-per-abi`. It output three apk release for different architecture.

But this time i run the same command, it output only one apk which is **armeabi-v7a**

Console output:

```
PS C:\Users\maple\Documents\Android Stuff\bmi_calculator> flutter build apk --split-per-abi
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                                
Parameter format not correct -
Note: C:\src\flutter\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\url_launcher-5.4.11\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\urllauncher\WebViewActivity.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Calling mockable JAR artifact transform to create file: C:\Users\maple\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\c52eca368d68b4a2662e6554875665fc\android.jar with input C:\Users\maple\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platforms\android-28\android.jar
Removed unused resources: Binary resource data reduced from 639KB to 503KB: Removed 21%
Removed unused resources: Binary resource data reduced from 639KB to 503KB: Removed 21%
Removed unused resources: Binary resource data reduced from 639KB to 503KB: Removed 21%
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'... Done                     320.1s (!)
√ Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-armeabi-v7a-release.apk (6.4MB).
```

Flutter doctor:

```
PS C:\Users\maple\Documents\Android Stuff\bmi_calculator> flutter doctor -v
[√] Flutter (Channel beta, 1.20.0-7.4.pre, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.959], locale en-MY)
    • Flutter version 1.20.0-7.4.pre at C:\src\flutter\flutter
    • Framework revision 916c3ac648 (13 days ago), 2020-08-01 09:01:12 -0700
    • Engine revision d6ee1499c2
    • Dart version 2.9.0 (build 2.9.0-21.10.beta)

 
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2) 
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\maple\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.2
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java       
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

[√] Android Studio (version 4.0)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin version 48.0.2
    • Dart plugin version 193.7361
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)

[√] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2019.3)
    • IntelliJ at C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.3.3
    • Flutter plugin version 48.0.2
    • Dart plugin version 193.7361

[√] VS Code (version 1.48.0)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\maple\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.13.2

[√] Connected device (3 available)
    • Web Server (web) • web-server • web-javascript • Flutter Tools
    • Chrome (web)     • chrome     • web-javascript • Google Chrome 84.0.4147.125
    • Edge (web)       • edge       • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 84.0.522.59

• No issues found!
```

Edit; It's okay now, not a big deal, just an issue with the tools outputting the generated files.

Comment: Have you checked the directories? It might just be a bug that it does not print all outputs. https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android#build-an-apk

Comment: Do you have any abi filter in your gradle files ?

Comment: Thanks @Er1,  yes all the outputs in the right folder as expected, but didn't show in terminal.

Answer (score 3):

You can try this

```
flutter build apk --target-platform android-arm,android-arm64,android-x64 --split-per-abi
```